# Excception when Implementing RPC permissions Security Management

Tags: corda

I am using corda_release_version = 'corda-3.1-snapshot'.

Web server not started when we specify RPC permissions Security Management
configuration in node.conf file.

Below are the details.

[INFO ] 2018-03-19T04:16:44,202Z [main] Main.main - Starting as webserver on localhost:10007 {}
[INFO ] 2018-03-19T04:16:44,453Z [main] BasicInfo.logAndMaybePrint - Starting as webserver: localhost:10007 {}
[ERROR] 2018-03-19T04:16:44,609Z [main] internal.NodeWebServer.retryConnectLocalRpc - Cannot start WebServer {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The node config has not specified any RPC users
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.connectLocalRpcAsNodeUser(NodeWebServer.kt:192) ~[corda-webserver-impl-corda-3.1-snapshot.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.retryConnectLocalRpc(NodeWebServer.kt:172) [corda-webserver-impl-corda-3.1-snapshot.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.start(NodeWebServer.kt:45) [corda-webserver-impl-corda-3.1-snapshot.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.WebServer.main(WebServer.kt:64) [corda-webserver-impl-corda-3.1-snapshot.jar:?]
[ERROR] 2018-03-19T04:16:44,609Z [main] Main.main - Exception during node startup {}

Below is my node.conf for PartyA node :-

```
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
p2pAddress="localhost:10005"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10006"
    adminAddress="localhost:10046"
}

webAddress="localhost:10007"

rpcUsers=[]
security = {
    authService = {
        dataSource = {
            type = "DB",
            passwordEncryption = SHIRO_1_CRYPT,
            connection = {
                jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/r3users"
                username = "postgres"
                password = "root"
                driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            }
        }
        options = {
            cache = {
                expireAfterSecs = 2
                maxEntries = 10000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to create an RPC user to log into the webserver. Are you using `deployNodes` to create the nodes you're running? If so, could you add your `deployNodes` block to the answer?

Comment: Joel, As I mentioned I am accessing User permissions using 'security' configuration in node.conf, 
and we know that we need to remove 'rpcUsers' entry from deployNodes task.
So deos it mean that the Web server is tighly coupled with 'rpcUsers' in deployNodes task?
If so How to resolve this?

Comment: please check I added the node.conf details.

Answer (score 1):

In Corda 3, configuring the built-in webserver using external credentials is not supported.

In Corda 4, the built-in webserver will have a separate configuration file where you can configure the credentials to be used by the webserver.